# Wildcard IP addresses for an iSCSI target initiator-address doesn’t seem to work on CentOS 6

Tags: centos-6, iscsi

In `/etc/tgt/targets.conf` wildcard (`172.16.2.*`) not work with initiator-address. I'm preparing for Red Hat High Availability Clustering exam (EX436).

The student workbook says:

> With `tgtadm` command, You are allowed to use wildcards like 172.16.X.*
>   in an `--initiator-address` option if you want.

But this is configuration in `targets.conf` is not working with a wildcard:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

# rpmquery scsi-target-utils
scsi-target-utils-1.0.24-16.el6.x86_64

# cat /etc/tgt/targets.conf
....
<target iqn.2015-09.rhel6.storage1>
    backing-store /dev/mapper/vg_rhel6-clustorage1
    vendor_id ex436prep
    initiator-address 172.16.2.*
</target>

# tgt-admin -s
Target 1: iqn.2015-09.rhel6.storage1
    System information:
        Driver: iscsi
        State: ready
    I_T nexus information:
    LUN information:
        LUN: 0
            Type: controller
            SCSI ID: IET     00010000
            SCSI SN: beaf10
            Size: 0 MB, Block size: 1
            Online: Yes
            Removable media: No
            Prevent removal: No
            Readonly: No
            Backing store type: null
            Backing store path: None
            Backing store flags: 
    Account information:
    ACL information:
        172.16.2.*
```

But when I set `initiator-address` to the initiator’s IP address (`172.16.2.10`) in `targets.conf`, everything works as expected:

```
# cat /etc/tgt/targets.conf
...
<target iqn.2015-09.rhel6.storage1>
    backing-store /dev/mapper/vg_rhel6-clustorage1
    vendor_id ex436prep
    initiator-address 172.16.2.10
</target>

# tgt-admin -s
Target 1: iqn.2015-09.rhel6.storage1
    System information:
        Driver: iscsi
        State: ready
    I_T nexus information:
        I_T nexus: 1
            Initiator: iqn.2015-09.one:i1
            Connection: 0
                IP Address: 172.16.2.10
    LUN information:
        LUN: 0
            Type: controller
            SCSI ID: IET     00010000
            SCSI SN: beaf10
            Size: 0 MB, Block size: 1
            Online: Yes
            Removable media: No
            Prevent removal: No
            Readonly: No
            Backing store type: null
            Backing store path: None
            Backing store flags: 
        LUN: 1
            Type: disk
            SCSI ID: IET     00010001
            SCSI SN: beaf11
            Size: 2076 MB, Block size: 512
            Online: Yes
            Removable media: No
            Prevent removal: No
            Readonly: No
            Backing store type: rdwr
            Backing store path: /dev/mapper/vg_rhel6-clustorage1
            Backing store flags: 
    Account information:
    ACL information:
        172.16.2.10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following did the trick!

```
initiator-address 172.16.2.0/24
```